# Mapping String to enum jooq

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

Is there a straightforward way to map a field in MySQL to an enum in JOOQ?
The field is `USER_STATUS`, possible values are defined by

```java
public enum Status {
  ACTIVE, INACTIVE, SUSPENDED
}
```

I tried to use forcedType:

```xml
<forcedType>
    <userType>com.mycompany.Status</userType>
    <expressions>USER_STATUS</expressions>
</forcedType>
```

However, this did not trigger any changes in the generated code. I tried the lower and upper case, prefixed and postfixed the column name (user_status) with '.*'. Nothing seems to work.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`<forcedType/>` element](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/) has several operation modes, each of which requires one additional child element:

#### Data type rewriting

In this case, you would need a `<name/>` element to map `USER_STATUS` columns to another data type. This doesn't work with enum types, though.

#### Applying a converter or binding

One way to map database types to your own `<userType/>` is by applying either a `<converter>` (i.e. [`org.jooq.Converter`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Converter.html)) or `<binding/>` (i.e. [`org.jooq.Binding`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Binding.html)). Use this approach to get full control over the conversion between the database type and your user type. You could also use the built-in [`org.jooq.impl.EnumConverter`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/EnumConverter.html) for this.

The `EnumConverter` works for ordinal mappings and 1:1 string to `java.lang.Enum.name()` mappings. If your enum values in the database have unmappable strings (e.g. containing whitespace), then you need to apply a manual mapping / converter.

#### Applying an enum converter (jOOQ 3.10+)

The simplest solution is to use an `<enumConverter>true</enumConverter>` flag on your `<forcedType/>`, if you do not have any special cases, which will also apply the `org.jooq.impl.EnumConverter` for you. This is also documented for the [`<forcedType/>` element](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/).

The same rules as for `org.jooq.impl.EnumConverter` apply.

Comment: Lukas, you are the best!

Comment: Do you know where there are complete running examples?

Comment: Look for `<enumConverter>` in the linked manual page about the [`<forcedType/>` element](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/)